# JavaScript for loop diffi

Tags: javascript

Here is the code I wrote:

```
var breakfast=['chocolate cake','ramen','sweet potato pie','egg                                                           
custard','spicy tofu','in a restaurant'];
for (i=0;i<breakfast.length;i++){
   if (breakfast[0]='chocolate cake'){
console.log ('On Monday,we eat '+ breakfast[i] +' !');
} else if (breakfast[1]='ramen'){
console.log('On Tuesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +' !');
}else if(breakfast[2]='sweet potato pie'){
console.log('On Wednesday, we eat '+ breakfast[i] +'!');
}else if (breakfast[3]='egg custard'){
console.log('On Thursday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +'!');
}else if(breakfast[4]='spicy tofu'){
console.log('On Friday, we eat '+breakfast[i]+'!')}
else{
console.log('On weekend, we eat '+breakfast[i]+'!')}
```

Here is the output:

```
VM93:4 On Monday,we eat chocolate cake !
VM93:4 On Monday,we eat ramen !
VM93:4 On Monday,we eat sweet potato pie !
VM93:4 On Monday,we eat egg custard !
VM93:4 On Monday,we eat spicy tofu !
VM93:4 On Monday,we eat in a restaurant !
```

Can any body tell me why this happened and how to fix the code so Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday and weekend will all appear? Thank you.

Comment: you use a single = to assign. you use a double or triple == to compare.

Comment: if (breakfast[0]=='chocolate cake')

Comment: but u prolly wanna do if breakfast[i]

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the loop and checking each time if `breakfast[0]='chocolate cake'`, which it is, and then you print out the **current** breakfast `breakfast[i]`.

So, instead, you should be checking if `breakfast[i] == 'chocolate cake'`, etc.

**Here is the corrected code:** (run the snippet)

**Note:** your if statements contained the assignment character `=` and instead should have had the comparison operator `==`.

```js
var breakfast=['chocolate cake','ramen','sweet potato pie','egg custard','spicy tofu','in a restaurant'];

for (i=0;i<breakfast.length;i++)
{
   if (breakfast[i] =='chocolate cake')
   {
       console.log ('On Monday,we eat '+ breakfast[i] +' !');
   }
   else if (breakfast[i]=='ramen')
   {
       console.log('On Tuesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +' !');
   }
   else if(breakfast[i]=='sweet potato pie')
   {
       console.log('On Wednesday, we eat '+ breakfast[i] + '!');
   }
   else if (breakfast[i]=='egg custard')
   {
       console.log('On Thursday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!');
   }
   else if(breakfast[i]=='spicy tofu')
   {
       console.log('On Friday, we eat '+breakfast[i] + '!');
   }
   else
   {
       console.log('On weekend, we eat '+breakfast[i] + '!');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
breakfast[0]='chocolate cake
```

To

```
breakfast[0]==='chocolate cake’
```

Lookup JavaScript comparison operators

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. The equality operator in javascript is `==` not `=`, so `breakfast[0]='chocolate cake'` means assign the value not check for equality (which will always be truthy so the if condition will be true).
2. You should check with `breakfast[i]`, as in your code the first if is always true (if written correctly), namely `breakfast[0]=='chocolate cake'`, you need to check if the current item (breakfast[i]) is equal to a value.

Code:

```js
var breakfast = ['chocolate cake', 'ramen', 'sweet potato pie', 'egg custard', 'spicy tofu', 'in a restaurant'];
for (var i = 0; i < breakfast.length; i++) {
    if (breakfast[i] == 'chocolate cake') {
        console.log('On Monday,we eat ' + breakfast[i] + ' !');
    } else if (breakfast[i] == 'ramen') {
        console.log('On Tuesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + ' !');
    } else if (breakfast[i] == 'sweet potato pie') {
        console.log('On Wednesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!');
    } else if (breakfast[i] == 'egg custard') {
        console.log('On Thursday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!');
    } else if (breakfast[i] == 'spicy tofu') {
        console.log('On Friday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!')
    }
    else {
        console.log('On weekend, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing, to compare something you need to use === instead.

```
if (breakfast[0]==='chocolate cake')
```

And this condition is always TRUE. The first position of your array will always be 'chocolate cake'.

Change your code to use the 'i' on your checks.

```
for (i=0;i<breakfast.length;i++){
   if (breakfast[i]==='chocolate cake'){
console.log ('On Monday,we eat '+ breakfast[i] +' !');
} else if (breakfast[i]==='ramen'){
console.log('On Tuesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +' !');
}else if(breakfast[i]==='sweet potato pie'){
console.log('On Wednesday, we eat '+ breakfast[i] +'!');
}else if (breakfast[i]==='egg custard'){
console.log('On Thursday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +'!');
}else if(breakfast[i]==='spicy tofu'){
console.log('On Friday, we eat '+breakfast[i]+'!')}
else{
console.log('On weekend, we eat '+breakfast[i]+'!')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I identified some issues with your code which include using the assignment `=` operator instead of the equality `===` operator. Also you hard coded the indexes you were checking instead of using the value of `i` you defined in the loop.

Please see below for changes I made to correct the issues listed above:

```js
var breakfast = ['chocolate cake', 'ramen', 'sweet potato pie', 'egg',
  'custard', 'spicy tofu', 'in a restaurant'
];

for (let i = 0; i < breakfast.length; i++) {
  if (breakfast[i] === 'chocolate cake') {
    console.log('On Monday,we eat ' + breakfast[i] + ' !');
  } else if (breakfast[i] === 'ramen') {
    console.log('On Tuesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + ' !');
  } else if (breakfast[i] === 'sweet potato pie') {
    console.log('On Wednesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!');
  } else if (breakfast[i] === 'egg custard') {
    console.log('On Thursday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!');
  } else if (breakfast[i] === 'spicy tofu') {
    console.log('On Friday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!')
  } else {
    console.log('On weekend, we eat ' + breakfast[i] + '!')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons: -

1. You are trying to check if breakfast[1] = 'chocolate cake' which it does, the first element is always 'chocolate cake' you should be using breakfast[i]
2. when you do `breakfast[i]='chocolate cake'` you are assigning the value in to the variable, not testing for equality

> ```
> var breakfast=['chocolate cake','ramen','sweet potato pie','egg custard','spicy tofu','in a restaurant'];
> for (i=0;i < breakfast.length;i++){
>    if (breakfast[i]==='chocolate cake'){
>         console.log ('On Monday,we eat '+ breakfast[i] +' !');
>     } else if (breakfast[i]==='ramen'){
>         console.log('On Tuesday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +' !');
>     }else if(breakfast[i]==='sweet potato pie'){
>         console.log('On Wednesday, we eat '+ breakfast[i] +'!');
>     }else if (breakfast[i]==='egg custard'){
>         console.log('On Thursday, we eat ' + breakfast[i] +'!');
>     }else if(breakfast[i]==='spicy tofu'){
>         console.log('On Friday, we eat '+breakfast[i]+'!')
>     }else{
>         console.log('On weekend, we eat '+breakfast[i]+'!');
>     }
> }
> ```

You could also do: -

```
var day=['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Weekend'];
var breakfast=['chocolate cake','ramen','sweet potato pie','egg custard','spicy tofu','in a restaurant'];

for (i=0;i < breakfast.length;i++){

    console.log ('On ' + day[i] + ',we eat '+ breakfast[i] +' !');

}
```

Comment: You are so smart!